# Write a function that takes as input a list of these datetime strings and returns only the date in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

i want to  write a function that takes as input a list of these datetime strings and returns only the date in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format.

This is the dataframe

```
twitter_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Explore-AI/Public-Data/master/Data/twitter_nov_2019.csv'
twitter_df = pd.read_csv(twitter_url)
twitter_df.head()
```

This is the date variable

```
dates = twitter_df['Date'].to_list()
```

This is the code i have written

```
def date_parser(dates):
    """
    This is a function that takes as input a list of the datetime strings 
    and returns only the date in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format.
    """
    
    # for every figure in the date string
    for date in dates: 
        
         # the function should return only the dates and neglect the time
        return ([date[:4] + "-" + date[5:7] + "-" + date[8:-9]])
    
date_parser(dates[:3])
```

This is the output i get

```
['2019-11-29']
```

This is the expected output

```
['2019-11-29', '2019-11-28', '2019-11-28', '2019-11-28', '2019-11-28']
```

How do i do these?

Comment: maybe you want to use `yield` or a list comprehension or just a loop that appends to a list and then return that list? `return` exits the function and returns the value

Answer (score 1):

You can try using regex:

```
new_date_list = []
```

and then inside the loop:

```
new_date_list.append(re.findall(r"^\d{4}(-|\/)(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(-|\/)(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$",date))
```

Comment: it doesnt work

tells me 
``` 
name 're' is not defined```

Comment: need to `import re`.

Comment: now here's the thing, i'm required not to import anyother thing but to use only pandas and numpy for this

Comment: @JeremiahGyan without using a regex, it would not be possible (as far as I know) to extract the date from the string. The way you're currently doing would only work if the date is at the same position in the all strings

Answer (score 1):

Convert the Date Series to pandas datetime format and then format the date time:

```
twitter_df['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(twitter_df['Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Here, we are adding a new column, named `Date2`, for `twitter_df`

You can convert this to list using:

```
twitter_df['Date2'].to_list()
```

Output for `twitter_df['Date2']`

```
0      2019-11-29
1      2019-11-29
2      2019-11-29
3      2019-11-29
4      2019-11-29
          ...    
195    2019-11-20
196    2019-11-20
197    2019-11-20
198    2019-11-20
199    2019-11-20
Name: Date2, Length: 200, dtype: object
```